# Passing bytes instead of filepath in ffmpeg function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ffmpeg

[full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hst7i.png)

Good day, I'm new to python and was tasked to do video compression and I found ffmpeg library, my problem is it requires the filepath of the file but I don't really intend to save the file locally.

Is it possible to use bytes instead of filepath for this?

thank you.

Comment: You should add the entire code in your question so that we can copy it and debug it.

Comment: ffmpeg can output via a pipe if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No.  It may not be obvious, but the Python `ffmpeg` library is just a wrapper around the incredibly powerful `ffmpeg` command line tool.  Thus, the compression is happening in a separate process that does not share your memory.